# Docker in Docker for Gitlab CICD pipeline

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, amazon-ecr

I am using GitLab runner in a docker container and registered it with my Score_Microservice project in Gitlab and registered a specific runner to this project.
now while writing a pipe-line I have a *requirement of converting my application.jar file into an image and publish that image to AWS ECR*.

I created a publish job that uses a base image as ubuntu and installed docker and awscli. But when the build step runs the job is failing with below exception...

**Error**:
$ docker build -t $AWS_DOCKER_REGISTRY/$AWS_APP_NAME:$CI_PIPELINE_ID .
**DEPRECATED: The legacy builder is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
Install the buildx component to build images with BuildKit:
https://docs.docker.com/go/buildx/
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1**

Note: My docker-compose file written for gitlab-runner has this /var/run/docker.sock mapping.

## **contents of .gitlab-ci.yaml  **

image: gitlab/dind
services:
- docker:stable-dind
variables:
DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay
AWS_DOCKER_REGISTRY: 349291937330.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
AWS_APP_NAME: sonata-certification
KEY: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
SECRET: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION

stages:
- publish

docker-publish-job:
image:
name: ubuntu:20.04
entrypoint: [""]
services:
- docker:dind
before_script:
- apt-get update && apt-get install docker.io -y
- docker --version

```
    - export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
    - apt install awscli -y
    - aws --version

    - aws configure set aws_access_key_id $KEY
    - aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $SECRET
    - aws configure set default.region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
    - aws configure set default.output json

stage: publish

script:
    - cd ScoreMicroservice
    - docker build -t $AWS_DOCKER_REGISTRY/$AWS_APP_NAME:$CI_PIPELINE_ID .

    - aws ecr get-login-password --region ap-south-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_DOCKER_REGISTRY
    - docker push $AWS_DOCKER_REGISTRY/$AWS_APP_NAME:$CI_PIPELINE_ID
```

## Contents of docker-compose

services:
gitlab-runner:
image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
restart: always
container_name: gitlab-runner
volumes:
- ./config/:/etc/gitlab-runner/
- //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
command: ["run", "--user=gitlab-runner", "--working-directory=/home/gitlab-runner"]
privileged: true

Find a solution to connect with AWS ECR and publish an image using a job in gitlab pipeline provided that I have my gitlab-runner being run in from docker container.